# Set-AzureStorageBlobContent places all files in root

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` to upload files to my blob:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse) {  
  Set-AzureStorageBlobContent 
    -Blob $file.Name 
    -Container $container 
    -File $file.FullName 
    -Context $context -Properties $prop -Force
}
```

This works but all the files in subfolders in the `$path` folder are placed in the root folder of the storage blob.

For example in my `$path` directory (the source files) I have a folder called `graphic` inside that folder I have my images `image1.png` so the structure is:

```
graphic
  image1.png
index.html
```

When I run the `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` task it uploads the `image1.png` into the root folder instead of creating a `graphic` folder and placing it in there.

Is it possible to keep the folder structure when uploading files using `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have mentioned it in my previous answer.

This is due to the `-Blob $file.Name`, for example, if the file a.txt is located at `d:\temp\sub\a.txt`, then the $file.name is a.txt. So when upload to blob statorage with the cmdlet `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, it always in the root folder.

The solution is that you should pass `sub\a.txt` instead of `a.txt` for the `-Blob` parameter.

First, define a variable for the root path of local folder, like `$path = "D:\temp\"`, then for the -Blob parameter for `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, use `-Blob $_.FullName.Replace($path,'')`.

Then you can check it on azure portal, the file a.txt should be in `root/sub/a.txt`

Comment: Oops, sorry! I found the solution to my previous question myself so I didn't implement your code :).

Answer (score 0):

Like Ivan said the issue was the `-Blob` value. I ended up using a slightly different solution though. Since the FullName value is something like this:

```
D:\a\r1\a\_ClientWeb-Build-CI\ShellArtifact\out\build\graphic\email-empty.svg
```

I used a `.split()` function to get the subfolder I needed:

```
-Blob $file.FullName.split('\', 9)[8]
```

> graphic\email-empty.svg

The complete command:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $file.FullName.split('\', 9)[8] -Container $container -File $file.FullName -Context $context -Properties $prop -Force
```